# Dynmically created DOM elements in extension not appearing for some Mac users

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, geturl

I have written a Chrome extension for Google Meet that adds a div to the Meet page and also includes a select and number of images - see links to extension and GitHub repository below:
[screenshot showing working extension on Windows machine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGSAn.png)
For some reason or other, the select and images do not appear for some users (who I believe are all using Chrome on a Mac)... or perhaps, the images appear briefly on the screen and then go away.
The screens look like this:
[screenshot showing missing elements on the MAC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pKeiU.png)

The following function adds the images to the div:

```
    function addElement(p, e, i, ti, cl){
        let de=document.createElement(e)
        de.id=i
        de.title=ti
        if(!!cl) de.classList.add(cl)
        if(e==='img') de.src = chrome.runtime.getURL("images/"+i+".png");
        p.appendChild(de)
    }
```

When you inspect the code; all of the DOM elements exist and if you hover over the scr attributes for the  tags, the images appear properly.  They just don't appear on the screen.

I have the following in my manifest.json:

```
"web_accessible_resources": [
        "images/*.png"
    ],
```

The person is using the latest version of the extension; he's cleared his cache and manually deleted the LocalStorage variables for the extension.  He's also uninstalled and re-added the extension.  All to no avail

Link to Extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fkdjflnaggakjamjkmimcofefhppfljd
Link to GitHub: https://github.com/al-caughey/Google-Meet-Attendance
Any suggestions?  TIA

Al

Answer (score 0):

If they appear on the HTML but they are not rendering, it is definitely a client side issue. Since they are images, is there anyway you can host them online? If not, it sounds like adblock is filtering the HTML on a case by case basis.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, the problem was clashing CSS
The images were `buttons` so I gave them a class named `btn`.  Another extension that is commonly installed when mine is, also defined a class with the same name (and it was hiding my buttons).

I changed the class name et voila, there they were.